# Why would my job work in local Hudson server but not in a remote Hudson server?

Tags: svn, hudson, jenkins-plugins, jobs

I have configured a job in a local hudson server.

I didnt check "Ignore externals option", for that externals to be checked-out.

This works in my local Hudson Server perfectly, everything is checked out. 
But this doesn't work when I do the same configuration for my job in a remote Server.

For credentials of the SVN repository address, I'm using my domain account in both (local and remote job hudson).

Please, what might be the problem? (I'm getting crazy...)

Thank you a lot

Comment: did you use file externals? What is your SVN version? What are the Server versions? Is your question for Hudson or Jenkins?

Comment: My question is for Hudson, but while looking in internet for a solution, I found out some people complain of the same problem under Jenkins and Hudson...

Comment: What about the other questions. I had an issue like that recently where my file-externals were not checked out in Jenkins. The reason was that the SVN workspace compatibility was set to 1.5 in the main configuration. file externals were introduced in SVN 1.6.

Comment: This might be the problem! Where can I find the files that show each-one version? Thank you!

Comment: In Jenkins it is the main configuration of the Jenkins server. "Managed Jenkins" -> "Configure System" then look for subversion settings. (haven't touched Hudson since Jenkins came around)

Comment: I believe it must be almost the same for hudson. is there any command lines to check the SVN workspace version and the main configuration version?? I dont have access rights to Hudson configuration

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, this didn't fix the problem. Could it be related to "credentials" storing?? I mean, when it reach that SVN repository, it checks if it its credentials are stored in the remote hudson, then if it exist it is checked.

Comment: Usually the svn server logs contain failed login events. What do the logs say?

Comment: it doesn't say explicitly that it couldnt checkout the externals. In "Add step", I have a script that generate the solution, and there some headers are missing, because they would come from those externals.

Comment: So what do the logs of these external svn server say?

Comment: Well, when doing the checkout manually for in a local hudson, an authentication request would popup for login and password once it needs an external. To store passwords, I check that I want tortoiseSVN to store authentication data when every popup of authentication request. At this way, finally tortoiseSVN that my local hudson use has stored all the necessary credentials, and so when runing the job that make the checkout in local hudson it works. the passwords are saved under C:\..\Application Data\Subversion\auth\svn.simple . But when running the job in a remote hudson server, this fails.

Comment: The logs say no error about externals. The externals when not checked out, headers (that exist in the externals) would be missing. And so when generating the solution, I would get error such as "file not found"...

Comment: I try to ask again. Do you have access to the logs the SVN server that contains the externals? I am not talking about the logfiles of your hudson server.

Comment: Can you please tell me under which I can find these logs and what is their default name and extension for that I can verify now? Thank you. (I'm new to Hudson)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42515/discussion-between-peter-schuetze-and-farah)

Comment: Hi! Chatting is blocked at work. As soon as i'm at home, i'll log, with hope u would be logged to. Thank you a lot for ur aim to help people over here. :)